# Can not able edit Provision profile on apple developer

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile

I am trying edit my Provision profile on apple developer account (I have added new device UDID in devices and now i wanted add in my Provision profile) but problem is that my edit button is not active Please let me know how to solve it.

Note ::  I dont wanted to delete my Provision profile.

Please check attach screen shot for more details [image: Screen]

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to edit that, look at the top right of the title bar: "(Managed by Xcode)" which means it will happen automatically by Xcode. That is also stated in the "Status" line. You only have to manage distribution profiles manually.

Comment: So then what should i need to do? I tried connecting my device to xcode and try to run but it shows me error "Valid PP for this excitable was not found". Even i check my Provision profile name that is also correct..Plz can u help out

Answer (score 0):

This provisioning profile is added (or eventually modified) by XCode when you click to "Add device to portail". (You have to enter Developer account then)

I've never modified these provisioning profiles nor used it. I create my self my own provisioning profile via the Apple Member Center site. You can give your provisioning profiles a name in order to distinguish them.